# What's the difference between a Hubot Package and a Hubot Script?

Tags: hubot

I'm using Hubot with Slack and I have already successfully integrated quite a few different NPM packages with it.

I'm considering developing some new functionalities but I'm not sure how to proceed.

How do I determine if what I need to do is properly accomplished by a Script? Or, when to use an NPM Package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference.

On the official website: ["Hubot / GitHub"](https://hubot.github.com/) as of December/15 we can see this description and links:

> We also maintain a: [repository of community Hubot scripts](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts) and [an organization of community Hubot packages](https://github.com/hubot-scripts) that you can add to your own robot.

The first link (https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts) links to a GitHub Repo called "github/hubot-scripts" and the second one links to a GitHub Organization called "Hubot Scripts" that is actually a collection of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It's better always write as a npm plugin if you want share with others
You can use this as template https://github.com/gasolin/webby-plugin

In fact, there's no difference
https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/bin/hubot#L104

but with npm plugin you can define your plugin library dependencies better